# A club with $x$ members is organized into four committees such that

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A club with $x$ members is organized into four committees  such that

(a) Each member is in exactly two committees

(b) Any two committees have exactly  one person in common.

Then $x$ has

(1) exactly two values both between  $4$ and $8$

(2) exactly one value that lies between $4$ and $8$

(3) exactly two values both between  $8$ and $16$

(4) exactly one value that lies between $8$ and $16$ .

Which one/one of this options are correct ?

I ran out of all ideas . Help needed . Complete solution will be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions a) and b) mean that there is a bijection from people to (unordered) pairs of committees. So how many pairs of committees are there?

Comment: There are $\frac {4 \times 3}{2}=6 $ , right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

consider a complete graph on four points $K_4$ and what the edges and vertices represent here.

[image]

Then consider how to add more members satisfying (a) and (b)

Answer (score 0):

Think like this: each committee should have exactly member in common. Take C1 and give it 3 members common with each. Now, take C2. It already has one member. Give it 2 more who are in C3 and C4 respectively. Similarly, take C3 which already has 2 members. Give it another member who is also in C4. Now, total members = 6. Adding another member to any committee will break the condition.